# Up arrow key not toggling commands within redis-cli (linux server)

Tags: redis, redis-cli

On a Ubuntu-based production server, I usually toggle through redis keys inside `redis-cli` by just pressing the up arrow key.

I suddenly find that this isn't working any more. Ergo, there's nothing shown after pressing the up arrow key, even if I've left a trail of commands.

All other commands are working correctly (I tried `info`, a bunch of `lrange` and `zrange` commands for example). The arrow-key behavior works correctly on `localhost` as well.

By the way, this issue is specific to `redis-cli`. The terminal correctly allows me to toggle through linux commands via the arrow-key.

Is something corrupted within `redis-cli`? Would be great to get advice from someone who's experienced this problem. In case it matters, `redis-cli -v` displays `redis-cli 4.0.2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same behavior using the Terminal app on OS X to connect to and AWS EC2 running Ubuntu: the arrows keys worked perfectly fine except in redis-cli.  Ultimately, I opened a new Terminal tab the arrows worked fine again in redis-cli.

Comment: Any idea whether this a `redis-cli` bug?

Comment: I'm not sure. I actually found your post looking for a solution myself. I tried several things trying to update redis-tools etc..., but in the end it just seemed to be tied to the Terminal app on my laptop.

Comment: Same thing happened to me... up-arrow stopped working in `redis-cli` even though it worked everywhere else, opened a new terminal & it started working again. Very frustrating! Using Windows Terminal to SSH into an Ubuntu VM.

Comment: Probably some form of redis-cli bug which makes it break, happens to me semi-regularly.